# How to find very bad result considering standards?

Tags: database, cluster-analysis, correlation, analysis, data-analysis

I have a data about air quality. Each attributes related to cocentration of it.
So, question is:

How to find very bad row with consedering Air Quality Standarts?

Is it Correlation coefficient? Or Could you give me any advice about formula?

Comment: Please read [ask].  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mathematical answer to this.

It's a matter of what *you* define as bad.

High O2 levels are good (well, at least as high as we realistically can get. 100% O2 would cause a lot of damage), high O3 however is bad (Ozone) in the lower air layers (but you do want the protective Ozone layer). Don't expect any algorithm to figure out that O2 is good, and O2 is bad, in that particular task...